# Conditionally aborting in a Bash alias

Tags: bash, alias

I have an alias:

```
alias local='if [ -z "${FUNCNAME[0]}" ]; then builtin local; fi; declare'
```

Which I want to use to redirect local commands into my modified declare function, which then can declare the variables, and only use the `builtin local` to get error messages if outside an function.

The alias has an output of (using set -x):

```
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ builtin local
-bash: local: can only be used in a function
+ declare
```

Right now it executes the `declare` anyways and I would like it to exit if the check fails. I can't use a function for this.

So far I've tried return, break and exit (exit not here for obvious reasons):

```
alias 'local=if [ -z "${FUNCNAME[0]}" ]; then builtin local; return 1; break; fi; declare'

+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ builtin local
-bash: local: can only be used in a function
+ return 1
-bash: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
+ break
-bash: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
+ declare
```

Example:

```
# When outside an function
local some_var=val
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ builtin local
-bash: local: can only be used in a function
# That's it

# When inside an function func
local some_var=val
+ '[' -z func ']'
+ declare some_var=val
# Uses my modified declare function
```

Comment: Are you trying to shadow the `local` keyword?  Anyway, why not put `declare` in an `else` block if you don't want it to run every time?

Comment: doesn't `local: can only be used in a function` explain it ? Don't do that! ;-) Anything that is going to take variable arguments should be written as a function. Good luck.

Comment: @Eric Renouf If I put the declare inside an else block, it won't be able to declare variables, see my update.

Comment: Your edit looks promising, but I never saw a use-case mentioned, so I guessed about what you were doing (incorrectly). Best to include some context of inputs and required outputs /vs current outputs. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `builtin local` is only used to get the error message, this will work:

```
alias local='builtin local 2>&1 >/dev/null; [ -n "${FUNCNAME[0]}" ] && declare'
```

It will always print only the error, if not inside a function, but won't print out all the local variables if inside one:

```
$> func () { local var2=foo; local var=bar; echo $var; }
$> func
+ func
+ builtin local
+ '[' -n func ']'
+ declare var2=foo
+ builtin local
+ '[' -n func ']'
+ declare var=bar
+ echo bar
bar
```

This way local gets replaced by declare, which then I can modify with a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need such an alias.  In any case, don't use an alias for this.  Use a function instead:

```
local() {
  if [ -z "${FUNCNAME[0]}" ]; then
    builtin local "$@"
  else
    declare -g "$@" # -g (for global) is necessary - otherwise variable set by declare would be local to the function
  fi
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure an function inside a function can't make global variables, can you confirm that?

Comment: As it is now, this would always return true because it's inside an function named 'local'

Comment: @BonBon, Then check `[ ${#FUNCNAME[@]} -gt 2 ]`, or `[ "${FUNCNAME[1]}" = main ]`. For testing, you can `declare -p FUNCNAME` to see what other things you might be able to test for.

Comment: @codeforester, the exception would be that `declare -g` would not work if the function was wrapped in round braces instead of curly ones, as it would put the function in a subshell.

Comment: Wouldn't `builtin local` just define a variable local to the outer `local`, not the function that actually *calls* `local`? Not that it matters here, because `FUNCNAME[0]` will never be empty; it's going to hold the name of `local`, the currently executing function.